# sent emails getting cut off

Tags: email

every so often i send an email to someone from my androids email app and the message gets cut off somewhere in the middle
example:

> hi buddy
>
> it was great talking to you yesterday, would you come tomor

i cant find any rhyme or reason to when this happens, it can be ok for a few weeks, then one day happen to one email or more then go away, seems entirely random

its causing terrible miscommunications...

i only found one similar question online about it, but with no answer. here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/hte02K16JxM

**Addl Info**

1. the messages are clipped also in my sent items folder (viewed in standard gmail on desktop browser), and also by the recipient in his inbox
2. im using the standard email app. not the one form gmail.
3. im not using any template as far as i know of

please advise

**UPDATE**

i now find so.ething very odd

the email is not getting cut off necessarly towards the end, but raher per what was added later in time! i.e.

i write an email

> hi. how are you?

and then i wait a few seconds and then i edit it like this

> hi BUDDY! how are you?

then i press send, the recipient gets the 1st version, not the edited one! this is sooooo odd. as if theres some internal caching going on

btw,if it makes any difference, my macine is attached to a AirWatch policy system.

any ideas guys?

Comment: Which one gets cut off: Message in the inbox of the recipient, or the message in your sent box, or both? What email client you use, Gmail?

Comment: hi fellows! i added the additional data

Comment: does anyone have any idea whats going on? this is really important to me. id be glad to provide any additional data that might be neccessary. thanks!

Comment: can anyone please help? this is so annoying... its causing angry clients and misunderstandings all the time. thanks!

Comment: "standard email app" - Different manufacturers include different stock email apps, so what phone do you have? If it's from a no-marks manufacturer, it could just be a bug in the app.

Comment: hi. samsung note5. in any event i stopped using that app since... so at the moment its irelevant to me. thanks anyway!